# AS3 Android Air App, Music does not turn off when user leaves app

Tags: android, flash, actionscript-3

Hello I have a AS3 Android Application that is playing background music, but when the user leaves the application, the music still is playing in the background.  Is there a method to call that senses the user leaving the application so that I can turn off my music?
Thank you for your time,
Scientific

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this on an Adobe Air forum: http://forums.adobe.com/message/4075374#4075374
The following code will deactivate the application if it loses focus and reactivate the application if it regains focus.

```
     NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE , handleDeactivate, false, 0, true);

     function handleDeactivate(event:Event):void {
         //the app is now losing focus
         musicChannel.stop();
     }

     NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, handleActivate, false, 0, true);

     function handleActivate(event:Event):void {
         musicChannel= mySong.play();
     }
```

Hope this helps everyone.
Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

In your App.mxml you can add handlers for app open and close

```
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                        activate="open(event)" deactivate="close(event)">

    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
private function open(e:Event):void{
trace("open");
}
private function close(e:Event):void{
trace("close");
}
    ]]>

</fx:Script>
```

Comment: Hello, I do not see this file?  I have PublishSettings.xml, DOMDomcument.xml, MobileSettings.xml, and my app file, App.xfl file in my directory.

Comment: What I meant by app.mxml is the container mxml file created when you first start a project. It should be the only file with a <s:ViewNavigatorApplication> tag (if you're using a view based app)

Comment: OK, I see this file now, it was in a different folder than I expected.  I tried this tag and it threw a error and crashed the app when I tried to publish it to a device to test it out.

Comment: What was the error? Did you write the methods? I updated the answer with the full code

Comment: Hello, the error said, "cannot parse document."  Thank you for the updated code.